# Porqué mi ventana modal tambien visualiza el body? PHP, HTML, CSS, JQUERY

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, modal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]solicito alguna ayuda, tengo una ventana modal para cargar datos en una app, el problema es que cuando incorporo la ventana modal el body desaparece y este aparece debajo de la ventana modal.
Adjunto imagenes de la ventana modal con el body debajo, y el codigo de la ventana modal

```
<!--=====================================
```

MODAL AGREGAR PRODUCTO
======================================-->

-->

```
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

      <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar producto</h4>

    </div>

    <!--=====================================
    CUERPO DEL MODAL
    ======================================-->

    <div class="modal-body">

      <div class="box-body">

        <!--=====================================
        ENTRADA PARA EL TÍTULO
        ======================================-->

        <div class="form-group">
          
            <div class="input-group">
          
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i></span> 

              <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg validarProducto tituloProducto"  placeholder="Ingresar título">

            </div>

        </div>

        <!--=====================================
        ENTRADA PARA LA RUTA DEL PRODUCTO
        ======================================-->

        <div class="form-group">
          
            <div class="input-group">
          
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span> 

              <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg rutaProducto" placeholder="Ruta url del producto" readonly>

            </div>

        </div>

       <!--=====================================
        ENTRADA PARA LA RUTA DEL PRODUCTO
        ======================================-->

        <div class="form-group">
          
            <div class="input-group">
          
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i></span> 

              <select class="form-control input-lg seleccionarTipo">
                
                <option value="">Selecionar tipo de producto</option>

                <option value="servicio">Servicio</option>

                <option value="fisico">Físico</option>            

              </select>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!--=====================================
        ENTRADA PARA AGREGAR MULTIMEDIA
        ======================================-->

        <div class="form-group agregarMultimedia"> 

          <!--=====================================
          SUBIR MULTIMEDIA DE PRODUCTO VIRTUAL
          ======================================-->
          
          <div class="input-group multimediaVirtual" style="display:none">
            
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></span> 
          
             <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg multimedia" placeholder="Ingresar código video youtube">

          </div>

          <!--=====================================
          SUBIR MULTIMEDIA DE PRODUCTO FÍSICO
          ======================================-->
          
          <div class="multimediaFisica needsclick dz-clickable" style="display:none">

            <div class="dz-message needsclick">
              
              Arrastrar o dar click para subir imagenes.

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

       <!--=====================================
        AGREGAR CATEGORÍA
        ======================================-->

        <div class="form-group">
            
            <div class="input-group">
          
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-th"></i></span> 

              <select class="form-control input-lg seleccionarCategoria">
              
                <option value="">Selecionar categoría</option>

                <?php

                $item = null;
                $valor = null;

                $categorias = ControladorCategorias::ctrMostrarCategorias($item, $valor);

                foreach ($categorias as $key => $value) {
                  
                  echo '<option value="'.$value["id"].'">'.$value["categoria"].'</option>';
                }

                ?>

              </select>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!--=====================================
        AGREGAR SUBCATEGORÍA
        ======================================-->

        <div class="form-group  entradaSubcategoria" style="display:none">
          
           <div class="input-group">
          
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-th"></i></span> 

              <select class="form-control input-lg seleccionarSubCategoria">

              </select>

            </div>

        </div>

       <!--=====================================
        AGREGAR DESCRIPCIÓN
        ======================================-->

        <div class="form-group">
          
          <div class="input-group">
          
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span> 

            <textarea type="text" maxlength="320" rows="3" class="form-control input-lg descripcionProducto" placeholder="Ingresar descripción producto"></textarea>

          </div>

        </div>

        <!--=====================================
        AGREGAR PALABRAS CLAVES
        ======================================-->

        <div class="form-group">
          
            <div class="input-group">
          
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span> 

              <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg tagsInput pClavesProducto" data-role="tagsinput"  placeholder="Ingresar palabras claves">

            </div>

        </div>

        <!--=====================================
        AGREGAR FOTO DE PORTADA
        ======================================-->

        <div class="form-group">
          
          <div class="panel">SUBIR FOTO PORTADA</div>

          <input type="file" class="fotoPortada">

          <p class="help-block">Tamaño recomendado 1280px * 720px <br> Peso máximo de la foto 2MB</p>

          <img src="vistas/img/cabeceras/default/default.jpg" class="img-thumbnail previsualizarPortada" width="100%">

        </div>

        <!--=====================================
        AGREGAR FOTO DE MULTIMEDIA
        ======================================-->

        <div class="form-group">
            
          <div class="panel">SUBIR FOTO PRINCIPAL DEL PRODUCTO</div>

          <input type="file" class="fotoPrincipal">

          <p class="help-block">Tamaño recomendado 400px * 450px <br> Peso máximo de la foto 2MB</p>

          <img src="vistas/img/productos/default/default.jpg" class="img-thumbnail previsualizarPrincipal" width="200px">

        </div>

        <!--=====================================
        AGREGAR PRECIO, PESO Y ENTREGA
        ======================================-->

        <div class="form-group row">
           
          <!-- PRECIO -->

          <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">

            <div class="panel">PRECIO</div>
            
            <div class="input-group">
            
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="ion ion-social-usd"></i></span> 

              <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg precio" min="0" step="any">

          </div>

      </div>

        </div>

        <!--=====================================
        AGREGAR OFERTAS
        ======================================-->

      <!--  <div class="form-group">
          
          <select class="form-control input-lg selActivarOferta">
            
            <option value="">No tiene oferta</option>
            <option value="oferta">Activar oferta</option>
           
          </select>

        </div>

        <div class="datosOferta" style="display:none"> -->
        
          <!--=====================================
          VALOR OFERTAS
          ======================================-->

         <!-- <div class="form-group row">
              
            <div class="col-xs-6">

              <div class="input-group">
              
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="ion ion-social-usd"></i></span> 
                
                <input class="form-control input-lg valorOferta precioOferta" tipo="oferta" type="number" value="0"   min="0" placeholder="Precio">

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                 
              <div class="input-group">
                   
                <input class="form-control input-lg valorOferta descuentoOferta" tipo="descuento" type="number" value="0"  min="0" placeholder="Descuento">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-percent"></i></span>

              </div>

            </div>

          </div> -->

          <!--=====================================
          FECHA FINALIZACIÓN OFERTA
          ======================================-->

         <!-- <div class="form-group">
              
            <div class="input-group date">
                  
              <input type='text' class="form-control datepicker input-lg valorOferta finOferta">
                  
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                      
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                  
              </span>
             
            </div>
          
          </div> -->

          <!--=====================================
          FOTO OFERTA
          ======================================-->

        <!--  <div class="form-group">
            
            <div class="panel">SUBIR FOTO OFERTA</div>

            <input type="file" class="fotoOferta valorOferta">

            <p class="help-block">Tamaño recomendado 640px * 430px <br> Peso máximo de la foto 2MB</p>

            <img src="vistas/img/ofertas/default/default.jpg" class="img-thumbnail previsualizarOferta" width="100px">

          </div>

        </div>
      
      </div> 

    </div> -->

    <!--=====================================
    PIE DEL MODAL
    ======================================-->

    <div class="modal-footer">

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary guardarProducto">Guardar producto</button>

    </div>

   <!-- </form> -->

 </div>
```

Comment: Debes añadir un ejemplo mínimo en el que se verifique el problema en cuestión, hay demasiado contenido innecesario en el código que proporcionas.

Comment: Además de que faltan las primeras líneas del modal. Probablemente lo que te esté pasando es que te falte alguna etiqueta </div> en el modal y te esté cerrando el modal con el body. Comprueba el código del modal que tenga una etiqueta </div> por cada <div> que abre. Y no es mala práctica colocar los modales al final del documento, justo antes del </body>

Comment: Digi si, estoy tratando de editar la consulta para poder incorporar bien el codigo. Las etiquetas estan bien, el modal está antes del body ya que trabajo sobre una estructura MVC, ahora, no comprendo porque hace eso, yo puedo sacar el boton, dejar el modal en codigo y me va a seguir sin mostrar el body de ninguna ruta, se lo come todo.

Comment: Ariel, comprendo, de que manera podría mostrar mejor mi error?

Comment: Digi, muchas gracias, si era las etiquetas! Sabía que era por ahi, y estaba convencido que estaba bien, ya no dan abasto los ojos

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos

Comment: Cuando tengo elementos tan grandes en html suelo añadir este tipo de comentarios que me ayudan a comprender mejor que etiqueta cierra a cual `<div class=container>` ... `</div><!--//container-->`. Muchas veces al intentar simplificar mi código para proporcionar un ejemplo mínimo verificable, encuentro solo el problema y me ahorro tener que abrir una pregunta en SO